# CCXT Library in Python: Handling 'Withdrawals through SAPI not permitted' Error for Remittance

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

I use the CCXT library in Python to perform withdraw.
I get the following error, what is the problem?

> Please note that withdrawals through SAPI are not permitted. to facilitate the withdrawal process, please use the official Binance website or mobile application.

The code I am running is as follows

```
import ccxt

api_key = "*****"
api_secret = "*****"

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': api_secret,
})

currency = 'XRP'  
amount = '25'  
address = "*****"  
tag = "*****"  

result = exchange.withdraw(currency, amount, address, tag)
print(result)
```

What I have tried is as follows

- Allow IP addresses
- White list the recipient of the money transfer